# Microsoft.Web.Administration Ssl cert not selected in iis manager

Tags: c#, iis

I'm playing around with this Microsoft.Web.Administration library to automate deployment of some legacy asp.net webform applications. Everything works except the https binding. The code doesn't give any errors and the site is created with https bindings, only the certificate is not showing as selected in iis manager. Below is the code I used to add the https binding. As you can see in the screenshot it is added, but nothing in the selected dropdown :(
I'm running the code on my local machine. I tested with a reference to Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll from my machine (version 7) and one I copied from the server (version 10), not the NuGet package (this doesn't work for reasons).

Any ideas how to get the certificate to be selected in iis?

--Edit--
When running the code locally on the server the cerificate is selected in the iis manager. Code is a little different of course.
`using (var iis = new ServerManager())...//instead of OpenRemote()`
and
`var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine); ...//instead of new X509Store(@"\\MyServer\My", StoreLocation.LocalMachine)`

Thx,
Bruno

```
    var store = new X509Store(@"\\MyServer\My", StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
    var cert = store.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.FriendlyName == "WMSVC-SHA2");
    var binding = site.Bindings.CreateElement(); 
    binding.SslFlags = SslFlags.None;
    binding.CertificateHash = cert.GetCertHash();
    binding.CertificateStoreName = store.Name;
    binding.Protocol = "https";                    
    binding.BindingInformation = "*:49102:";                    
    store.Close();
    site.Bindings.Add(binding);
```

[image]

Comment: Why `@"\\MyServer\My"`? Are you trying to use MWA to manage a remote server?

Comment: Yes. I'm using ServerManager.Openremote("\\\\MyServer") to get an instance to iis. I can add the site with the https binding and it shows in a browser when I take a look at the site information (the little lock thingy). So the certificate is bound to the site, it's just not showing in iis manager on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see this certificate in IIS, you need to install Microsoft.Web.Administration Ssl cert to your IIS. For specific steps, you can refer to the Manual Intermediate Installation Instructions section in this [link](https://www.thesslstore.com/knowledgebase/ssl-install/microsoft-iis-7-ssl-installation/).

Comment: the certificate is already installed on the server and working, that's not the issue (see edit in original question).

Comment: Do you mean that you can't see the certificate that has been working properly in IIS?

Comment: The certificate exists in the certificate store on the server. When running the code on the server, the dropdown in IIS manager is showing the selected certificate. When running the code from my machine the dropdown is not showing the certificate as selected. It is however bound to the site, because when I look at it in a browser it shows me the certificate.

Comment: You must install the certificate in your computer to select it in IIS.

Comment: You're not reading what I wrote. It all works fine when I run the code on the server. When I run it from my machine it doesn't show in the dropdown. All I need to do is find a way to run the code on the server when my build and deploy from Azure devops ends. Thanks for the effort, but I'll let it rest for now and take a look at it later with a clear mind.